# Laravel auth == true after User::create?

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

No user is currently logged in. Why after I create a user using a User::create() model (my application registration) which extends Eloquent does Auth say that the created user is now logged in?

```
var_dump(Auth::user());
$user = User::create(array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
));
var_dump(Auth::user());
```

outputs:

```
null

object(User)[204]
    protected 'table' => string 'users' (length=5)
    protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=5)
            0 => string 'username' (length=8)
```

Is this something related to the interfaces? How do I disable this? Incredibly annoying...

Comment: You must be firing an event somewhere and logging the user in elsewhere after User is created. When I run your code I get "null" and "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I wasnt destroying any current sessions. The solution is to run Auth::logout() before creating the user.